# webview.loadData() won't load local images

Tags: android

I have an html page that's built dynamically.  Some of the images come from an internet url and others i want to load from the Assets folder.  The pages correctly renders the internet images, however, it just refuses to load local images.  I'm tried many variations including the following and none will load the local images.  If everything is loaded from the internet url, the entire pages renders correctly but I really don't want to go to the internet for static content that won't change.  Any ideas?

String pageData="a bunch of html markup...";

//-- i had to remove the < from the img tag below to get by the spam filter on this forum-->

//--try 1-->
pageData += "img src='file:///data/data/(my package)/files/image1.png' alt='my image'>";

//--try 2-->
pageData += "img src='/data/data/(my package)/image1.png' alt='my image'>";

//--try 3-->
pageData += "img src=' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,'" + readAssetFileAsBase64("image1.png") + "' alt='my image'>";

//--try 4-->
explosives!

The page is rendered using..

webview.loadData(pageData,"text/html",null);

but I've also tried

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://", s, "text/html","windows-1252" ,null);

I can't use .loadUrl() since the page is built dynamically.  I suppose I could write the dynamic page out to disk the call .loadUrl() but that doesn't seem so efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you load the html with a base url, although that base url doesn't need to be anything pertinent

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", htmlString, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

and then you can reference things in the assets folder using something like this

```
file:///android_asset/image1.jpg
```

the "android_asset" path seems to be the thing you haven't tried yet.  If your files are not in your asset folder then you need to serve them with a ContentProvider, see this tutorial from my site: http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/02/20/serving-android-webview-resources-with-content-providers.html

Comment: Actually, you can use "file:///android_asset/" as the first parameter to webView.loadDataWithBaseURL, then you can reference the images in your html like this <img src="image1.jpg">, as the base URL is already specified.